# Setting up conditional routing in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I'm using CakePHP 2.7 and I have following routes defined in `app/Config/routes.php`:

```
Router::connect('/:state/:location/:slug',
    ['controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display_program'],
    ['pass'=> ['state', 'location', 'slug']]
);
Router::connect('/:state/:location/:degree_level/:slug',
    ['controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display_program'],
    ['pass'=> ['state', 'location', 'degree_level', 'slug']]
);
Router::connect('/:state/:location/:degree_level',
    ['controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'list_programs'],
    ['pass'=> ['state', 'location', 'degree_level']]
);
```

The problem that I'm encountering is when I'm passing three values, the third value can either be degree level or a slug.

```
/az/campus/program-name-slug [should route to pages->display_program()]

/az/campus/masters/program-name-slug [should route to pages->display_program()]

/az/campus/masters [should route to pages->list_programs()]
```

Right now all three urls route to display_program() action however I need the third one (without the slug) to route to list_program(). Any ideas much appreciated!

Comment: Is the degree level always distinguishable from the program name? ie, `masters` (and whatever other levels there might be) will never be the name of a program?

Comment: Correct, there are 4 degree levels: undergraduate, graduate, bridge, and doctorate. (I only used masters in the example to avoid confusion)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So if your degree levels never conflict with the program names, then you can use a simple regex to further narrow down what the `degree_level` element matches, something like

```
Router::connect('/:state/:location/:degree_level',
    ['controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'list_programs'],
    [
        'pass'=> ['state', 'location', 'degree_level'],
        'degree_level' => 'undergraduate|graduate|bridge|doctorate'
    ]
);
```

That way the `degree_level` element will only match in case one of four given strings is used.

In order for this to finally work you must put this route *before* the route with the `slug` element, otherwise the slug one will steal the route, as it greedily matches any string, ie finally you should have the routes ordered like

```
// specific count match, semi-specific value match
Router::connect('/:state/:location/:degree_level',
    // ...
);

// specific count match, greedy value match
Router::connect('/:state/:location/:slug',
    // ...
);

// sepcific count match, greedy value match
Router::connect('/:state/:location/:degree_level/:slug',
    // ...
);
```

See also **[Cookbook > Routing > Route Elements](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#route-elements)**